# Separate price and cents

Tags: price

I want to separate the price and decimals, to use this html for the price 49,95.

```
<span class="price">
49,
<span class="price-decimal"> 95 </span>
</span>
```

I currently use this line to load the price:

`<?php echo substr($_product->getPrice(), 0, -2) ?`>

How can I fix that?

Comment: off topic, purely php question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$first_amount_before_split = 29.95;

$my_array = explode(".", $first_amount_before_split);

echo $my_array[0]; // would be 29

echo $my_array[1]; // would be 95

Comment: :D  glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You may use search and look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518454/how-to-split-float-in-php
price is of float type in Magento.